# Stick whole table to its original position while scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make sticky table while scrolling the page. Currently I'm having two tables one after another, but when I'm scrolling the page, only first table moves about `10px;` and stops. Here is my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/StaG8/3/) and my tables don't move at all. Anyone, can advice me, what I'm doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<div id="header">
    header
</div>

<table class="table_filter_data filter_table" cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width='100%'>
    <tr>
        <td>
            table_1
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
        <table class="table_filter_data filter_table" cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width='100%'>
    <tr>
        <td>
            table_2
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

jQuery:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            function UpdateFilterHeaders() {
               $("div.div_filter_table").each(function() {                 
                var originalTable = $(".tableFloatingHeaderOriginal", this);
                var floatingTable = $(".tableFloatingHeader", this);

                var offset = $(this).offset();
                var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

                if ((scrollTop > offset.top) && (scrollTop < offset.top + $(this).height())) {
                    floatingTable.css("visibility", "visible");
                    originalTable.css("visibility", "hidden");
                    floatingTable.css("top", Math.min(scrollTop - offset.top, $(this).height() - floatingTable.height()) + "px");

                    // Copy cell widths from original header
                    $(floatingTable).each(function(index) {
                        var cellWidth = $(originalTable).eq(index).css('width');
                        $(this).css('width', cellWidth);
                    });

                    // Copy row width from whole table
                    floatingTable.css("width", $(this).css("width"));
                }
                else {
                    originalTable.css("visibility", "visible");
                    floatingTable.css("visibility", "hidden");
                    floatingTable.css("top", "0px");
                }
               });
            }

            $(document).ready(function() {

                $("table.filter_table").each(function() {
                    $(this).wrap("<div class=\"div_filter_table\" style=\"position:relative\"></div>");

                    var originalTable = $(this);                 
                    var clonedTable = originalTable.before(originalTable.clone()
                    .addClass("tableFloatingHeader")
                    .css("position", "absolute")
                    .css("top", "0px")
                    .css("left", $(this).css("margin-left"))
                    .css("visibility", "hidden"));

                    originalTable.addClass("tableFloatingHeaderOriginal");
                });
                UpdateFilterHeaders();
                $(window).scroll(UpdateFilterHeaders);
                $(window).resize(UpdateFilterHeaders);
            });   
        </script>
```

CSS:

```
body {height:2000px;}
.table_filter_data{ margin: 0px ; padding: 0px; padding-left: 3px; padding-top: 10px;}  
.table_filter_data > tbody > tr > td{ padding: 2px; text-align: left; font-size: 0.9em;}  
.table_filter_data > tbody > tr > td.title{ text-align: right;}               
.table_filter_data > tbody > tr > td > input{ font-size: 0.9em;}  
.table_filter_data > tbody > tr > td > select{ font-size: 0.9em;}  
#header {height: 100px; border: 1px solid gray}
```

Comment: Please include your code in the post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84342/answer-that-only-contains-a-link-to-jsfiddle

Comment: can you please put a fiddle?

Comment: @RupamDatta look at the description, it is a link to it. http://jsfiddle.net/StaG8/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using `position: fixed` for the tables that you want to be sticky.